# Please Recommend a HTML Prototype Builder

Tags: html, prototype, wireframe

I know some tools that can create wireframe for web site, but their output format is not HTML. I like HTML prototype since it can be interactive (via Javascript or VBScript) and I can share it on my web site too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com/), it is the specialized tool for this.

Comment: Thanks Ross, it is exactly the tool I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a combination of your favourite HTML editor and your favourite browser.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I want a specialized tool to create interactive prototype, it will be great if I don't need to write javascript or vbscript myself... Is it possible?